# $(a_n)$ diverges and $(b_n)$ converges, then $(a_n b_n)$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis

If $(a_n)$ diverges and $(b_n)$ converges, then $(a_n b_n)$ diverges. How can I prove that? I think this is true, but I can't prove it.

Comment: $b_n = 0$ will make a lot of things converge

Answer (score 3):

Simply False. Take $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $a_nb_n \to 0$ !!

Answer (score 3):

Take $a_n=n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$.
The product converges

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, this isn't true if $b_n \rightarrow 0$. So let's assume $b_n \rightarrow b \neq 0$. Then $1/b_n\rightarrow 1/b$.

If $a_nb_n \rightarrow c$ then $a_n \rightarrow c \times1/b = c/b$. (Since the limit of products is the product of limits.)

Therefore if $a_n$ diverges then $a_nb_n$ must diverge.